# Intellij error when importing build.gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

If I import a Java project into Intellij, then go to the command line and run gradle idea to tell Intellij that it's a gradle project. I get the following.

  `com/android/builder/model/NativeAndroidProject: Unsupported major.minor 
  version 52.0 Please use JDK8 or newer.
  Error: Download JDK8
  Select a JDK from the FileSystem.`

I click on the link and it takes me to Project Structure, SDK Location with 3 options, Android SDK Location, JDK Location (which is set right) and Android NDK location. Both android fields are blank but it gives me an error, The Android SDK location is inside the IDEA install location. Any attempt to set these directories results in sdk not found. I'm running version 2017.2.1.

Any time I try to sync gradle, I get that same message as above, even if I select jdk 8. Also, this is not an Android project and I don't have anything even remotely close to Android specific in the project. What is causing this and how do I fix?

[image]

[image]

Can't post the build.gradle but here are the plugins
  
  `apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'idea'
  apply plugin: 'groovy'
  apply plugin: 'application'
  apply plugin: 'maven'`

Answer (score 0):

It's a compiler issue, your code version and your jdk version doesn't match, either your code is compiled in java 1.6 and you are trying to build it in java .7 or java 1.8

Comment: I've edited the project sdk and set it to 1.6 a dozen times. External libraries shows 1.6.  I've also used Intellij for years and I've been able to change the jdks without problem. Since I upgraded, I've been caught in this loop. Why am I even getting an android error if I'm not doing anything with Android.

Comment: first of all compile the code in the same version, which you get when you do

Comment: I can't compile from intellij. It won't let me get that far. I keep getting the NativeAndoidProject 52 error. Tried setting to jdk 1.7. Same error although builds from command line with gradle build.

Comment: and your java version is also 1.7 ?? check out the environment variable

Comment: Even if I set the project jdk to 1.8 (shows up as 1.8 under external libraries in the project view so I know it applied), I still get the same jdk8 error.

Comment: When I ran from command line, I used sdkman to set to 1.7 and gradle worked. Same if I set it to 1.8u121.

Comment: Everything is set to 1.8 now. I restart intellij, go to terminal, java -version is 1.8. In project structure, it's 1.8, under external libraries, it's 1.8. In build.gradle, sourcecompatibility is 1.8. Still get the same error to install 1.8.  gradle build still works from command line.

Comment: Found an interesting error; Warning:java: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.sisu.scanners.index.SisuIndexAPT6' less than -source '1.8'

Comment: Booyah! Disabling annotation processing resolved it, although I don't know how I'm going to use lombok now. Preferences>Build Execution and Deployment>Annotation Processors> Uncheck enable annotation processing.

Comment: Nice Dave, Good you got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling annotation processing resolved it. Preferences>Build Execution and Deployment>Annotation Processors>

Then uncheck enable annotation processing.

Comment: The next option after enable, is "Obtain processors from project classpath", which is on by default. I'm assuming that since I didn't have lombok in this project, or another processor, that this is why I get the error here and not when I open my projects with lombok.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IntelliJ **Settings > Build Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle**.

Set the **Gradle JVM** JDK8 (or your preferred JDK).

Worked for me.